# PeopleSearchResults Page layout not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, people-search

I tried modifying the `PeoplesearchResults.aspx` page layout and from then on any pages created from this page layout displays the error

> "The base type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage' is not allowed for this page. The type  could not be found or it is not registered as safe. "

Even removing the changes from the Page layout or restoring the page layout to its initial version is not helping.

I am using SharePoint Online / Office 365.
Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have edited the page layout it de links from the content database, in order to roll back you have to use "Reset to Site definition" on ECB context menu of the layout. This is roll back your changes and it refers from the content database.